# Using the username or Page.User.Identity.Name for select parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have a login control inside a loginview control and on the loggedin template, there is a gridview and an sqldatasource.

What I need is to use the username to filter that gridview. But I always get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. I also tried adding .tostring to the page.user.identity.name

Take a look at my code below:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
<AnonymousTemplate>
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"  OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn">        
    </asp:Login>
</AnonymousTemplate>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [UserName], [Date], [TimeIn], [TimeOut], [Total] FROM [attendance] ORDER BY [Date] where username = @username ">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" />
    </SelectParameters>            
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

For the code-behind

```
Protected Sub Login1_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    TryCast(LoginView1.FindControl("SqlDataSource1"), SqlDataSource).SelectParameters("username").DefaultValue = Page.User.Identity.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Page.User.Identity.Name is not set until the page is re-loaded. So it is not available in LoggedIn event but instead you can simply use Login1.UserName. Since you hit the LoggedIn event it is confirmed that your credentials are valid.
In your case since the Login Control is inside of LoginView control, you will have to first get reference to that control something like below:

```
Protected Sub Login1_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

     Dim login1 As Login = DirectCast(sender, Login)
    TryCast(LoginView1.FindControl("SqlDataSource1"), SqlDataSource).SelectParameters("username").DefaultValue
= login1.UserName

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, then the error seems to be coming from SqlDataSouce1 being not found in the LoginView. Try moving it outside of LoginView and if it is outside then you don't have to find but just use directly. And what I said about User.Identity still remains true.

Comment: Ok, now everything works fine except that it doesn't display any data. I've already tested my t-sql script and it works fine on SSMS.

Comment: To what are your binding your SDS to? Try calling DataBind for that control.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Btw, I've tried using breakpoints and it seems the username doesn't get passed to the parameter. The parameter always displays NOTHING while the login1.username has a correct value.